# Why aren't these vectors equal?

Tags: c++, vector

I've created two vectors and filled the other one with push_back and the other one with indices. I would expect these to be equal but ther aren't. Can someone explain me why is this?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    vector<int> v0;
    v0.push_back(0);
    v0.push_back(1);
    v0.push_back(2);

    vector<int> v1;
    v1.reserve(3);
    v1[0] = 0;
    v1[1] = 1;
    v1[2] = 2;

    if (v0 != v1) {
            cout << "why aren't they equal?" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try resize. what you wrote is UB

Comment: You can't compare vectors like that. Vectors has a method that allows for comparison.

Comment: Just before your `if` try something like `cout << v1.size();` (and maybe `v0.size()`) and see if it doesn't give some indication about why they're not equal.

Comment: @EvanCarslake Of course one can [compare vectors like that](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp).

Comment: @sp2danny That should be an answer.

Comment: The answer is that `reserve()` only makes sure enough memory is available. It does not *create* new elements in the vector. So your comparison will not take into account the elements you set but that are not considered part of the vector. As @sp2danny says, you need `resize();`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
vector<int> v1;
v1.reserve(3);
v1[0] = 0;
v1[1] = 1;
v1[2] = 2;
```

This is probably an undefined behavior ( although not sure if it's implementation dependent).

You cannot use `operator[]` for filling up the vector as it's returning the reference to the underlying object which in your case is nothing other than bunch of bits.

You should either use `push_back()` OR just `resize` your vector.Using latter:-

```
vector<int> v1;
v1.resize(3);
v1[0] = 0;
v1[1] = 1;
v1[2] = 2;
```